# libcurl returns CURLcode 23

Tags: c, libcurl

Hello I'm currently working on a simple program to download a PNG file, but there is a problem when I use libcurl library.

Actually I first confirmed that this code works fine on WSL, but if I run this code with Windows (Visual Studio), curl_easy_perform returns CURLcode 23.

I searched this error code and I now know it means WRITE_ERROR, but I have absolutely no idea why it doesn't work.

Any helps are very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

```
char url[100] = "http://url_to.png"; // url directs to png file.
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
CURLcode res;
FILE *fp;
if (curl) {
    // Open file 
    fp = fopen("./sample.png", "wb");
    if (fp == NULL) { printf("File cannot be opened\n"); }
    else {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res) { printf("Cannot grab the image! Error Code: %d\n", res); // returns Error code 23 }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Comment: Could be SSL certificates from what I've heard. I don't know though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using libcurl as a win32 DLL, you [**MUST**](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) use a [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) if you set this option or you will experience crashes or lucky errors `CURLE_WRITE_ERROR`.

```
 static size_t cb(void *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
 {
   FILE *fp = userp;
   return fwrite(data, size, nmemb, fp);
 }

 // ...

 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, cb);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
```

Comment: You should include a reference to the remark regarding win32, since that is a literal quote from the API documentation. But it could be argued that OP `did` set this option, albeit to value `NULL`. So I would say the documentation is not sufficiently clear about this.

Comment: @Cheatah OP sets the default value, like they do not set it at all to a new curl easy handle. *Set this option to NULL to get the internal default function used instead of your callback.*

Comment: This answer plus type casting : `FILE *fp = (FILE*)userp;` was the answer for this problem.
Thank y'all!!

Comment: @IgnorantPotato No type casting from void pointer to any pointer is required in C.

Comment: @273K You are right. I didn't realize that my file was set as cpp file.